# How to find an error in a tcp server application having no source code

Tags: c++, c++-cli, integration, tcpclient, solution

I have a c++/cli tcp client application sending a data in a specific format like **`L,20100930033425093,-5.929958,13.164021`**
to a main application on port 9000.The main application is actually done by the other vendor and I dont have the source code for that.The programmer who developed that is no more with that company.

Now,I can communicate to the desired application using the IP and Port No.But the data supposed to be visible on the Main Application GUI is not showing up. But I used a different socket server demo application with same IP as the main application to receive the data I am sending.It works perfectly fine. Now I do not where the error is and whether the stream is received on the other side. How can I effectively solve this situation. I am asking this in a broader picture to get some ideas.

Any suggestions or discussion on this will be helpful?

Comment: Contact the application vendor?

Comment: I did..the programmer who did has left and the guy whom i contacted dont have much idea

Comment: Are you a paying customer of this main application? Do you have a support contract? If not theres IMHO not much you can do.

Comment: Did it work at one time, but it stopped working at some point?

Answer (score 1):

You can use packet sniffers to find out what data is being sent (for tcp I suggest fiddler), if its wrong then you can try modifying it in some middle app, then this app can send it to your gui app. I assume you have no source code for GUI app.